# Strange Hard Disk and Operating System Behaviour

Tags: linux, hard-drive, troubleshooting

When I was working on my laptop (Dell Inspiron), in which the OS is Kali Linux, I suddenly saw that the pictures- for example the terminal picture and the firefox picture on the left menu bar - along with the settings picture, lock, and turn off pictures are gone.

At this time, I can't open any program, and any command run on the terminal will result in an input/output error (I don't know why), and then kali turns to the terminal window (no desktop).

I then have to hard shutdown my laptop using the power key. this happened several times; every time I turn on the laptop, it lasts for about 15-20 minutes functioning normally then this happens.

Every time this happens I open the disk utility and check for the hard disk status: it says "disk is ok". However, running disks the last time showed "disk is ok, one failing attribute is failing". I quickly viewed the SMART data and self test and saw that everything is ok, except for the end-to-end error, which is failing. The Number of reallocated sector count is 0. So there is a number of questions:

1. What does input/output error when opening programs or running terminal commands mean?
2. What Keeps This happening although I was using the laptop normally and the hard disk is relatively new (I have no been experiencing that before) ?
3. What does this mean?
4. What shall I do to stop this from happening (already ran the self test)?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There is an End-to-End S.M.A.R.T error, which is failing.

Based on the above **your disk is failing**.

**Urgent data backup and hardware replacement is recommended.**

> **Hard drives, supporting this attribute**
>
> Samsung, Seagate, IBM (Hitachi), Fujitsu, Maxtor, Western Digital, Hewlett-Packard
>
> **Description**
>
> End-to-End error S.M.A.R.T. parameter is a part of HP's SMART IV
> technology and it means that after transferring through the cache RAM
> data buffer, the parity data between the host and the hard drive did
> not match. For detailed information see [SMART IV Documentation from
> HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01159621/c01159621.pdf).
>
> **Recommendations**
>
> This is a critical parameter. Degradation of this parameter may
> indicate imminent drive failure. **Urgent data backup and hardware
> replacement is recommended.**

Source [9119: S.M.A.R.T. Attribute: End-to-End error](https://kb.acronis.com/content/9119)

---

#### Background Reading

> **How SMART IV works**
>
> - SMART IV uses a 2 byte parity code to enable it to better detect if data is valid during transfers to and from the data buffer of the hard
>   drive. If the parity data does not match after transferring through
>   the cache RAM data buffer, then depending upon the command, the drive
>   can do a background retry to get data again or report the error
>   message to the host.
> - During a disk read, a 2 byte parity code is generated after the data is transferred from the disk. After transfer from the data buffer to
>   the drive interface, the parity data is checked (see Figure 1).
> - During a disk write, a 2 byte parity code is generated and appended to the data going into the data buffer. The parity code is checked
>   before it goes into the data buffer and before it is written to the
>   disk (see Figure 2).
> - If an error is detected by the drive and the data cannot be retrieved or sent without failure, a protocol is in place to notify
>   the host operating system of the error. The host operating system can
>   then decide to resend the command or notify the user that a data error
>   may have occurred.
> - If errors are detected, a SMART attribute called End-to-End Error Detection Count is updated. If the SMART threshold is crossed, an
>   imminent failure error message is reported to the user either through
>   Client Management Software that has been installed in the operating
>   system or by the HP BIOS on the next reboot. Since all HP BIOS issue
>   the SMART status command, no additional software is required.
>
> <kbd>[image]</kbd>

Source [SMART IV Documentation from HP](http://h20000.www2.hp.com/bc/docs/support/SupportManual/c01159621/c01159621.pdf).

Comment: thanks a lot for answering questions 3 and 4, but can you answer 1 and 2 please? also, is there no other way than replacing the HDD? the problem is that it is relatively new!

Comment: @DarkEagle 1/ If there are disk errors programs can behave unpredictably. 2/ Look at the failure rate for hard disks. It is a U shaped curve with failures being quite high for the first year. Dropping for the next few years. Then rising again. See [How long do hard drives actually live for?](http://www.extremetech.com/computing/170748-how-long-do-hard-drives-actually-live-for) for the gory details.

Comment: @DarkEagle If your disk is still relatively new you should be able to get a warranty replacement, either from Dell or the disk manufacturer.

Comment: can gparted help in that case?? or is it of no use?

Comment: @DarkEagle Your disk is failing. You cannot fix it. Buy a new one. **Urgent data backup and hardware replacement is recommended.**